# Is this really $SO(4)$ algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, lie-algebra, hydrogen, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

The commutation relations involving the components of Runge-Lenz vector of the Hydrogen atom problem, ${\vec A}$ and the angular momentum ${\vec L}$ are given by
$$ 
[L_i,L_j]=i\hslash\varepsilon_{ijk}L_k,\\
[A_i,A_j] = -i\hslash\varepsilon_{ijk} \frac{2H}{m} L_k,\\
[L_i,A_j]=i\hslash\varepsilon_{ijk}A_k
$$
I am doubtful about the commutation relation in the middle the right-hand side of which contains the Hamiltonian operator. The righthand side does not seem to be a simple linear combination of $L_1,L_2$ and $L_3$. If $H$ were a constant, then this is the same as $SO(4)$ algebra. But how can this be $SO(4)$ where ${H}$ is an operator? Any help?

Comment: Will "an operator commuting with all your generators behaves like a constant for all practical purposes" mean anything to you?

Comment: You should treat $H$ as a constant w.r.t. the $SO(4)$ generators - this is just the same thing as saying that $H$ is invariant under $SO(4)$ transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both the $L_i$ and the $A_i$ are constants of motion, their Poisson bracket with the Hamiltonian vanishes and so it is "as good as a constant" for purposes of the algebraic structure - like a constant, it commutes with everything. Essentially you get one differently scaled $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ algebra for each subspace defined by constant energy $H(q,p) = E$.

Comment: Just to be really precise, for $E<0$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind How about quantum mechanics? In that case, how do you scale the $A_i$'s to get the standard SO(4) algebra structure? Surely, we cannot divide by the square root of the hamiltonian operator.

Comment: @Solidification I don't know what you mean - you still get one $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ on each eigenspace of $H$.

Comment: Ah! I think I got it. You are saying that this set of commutation relations when applied to a subspace of the Hilbert space corresponding to a fixed energy $E$, is a SO(4) algebra. Is that right?