Showing that the angular momentum operators and Laplace-Runge-Lenz operator together are generators of $SO(4)$
This is a question that popped up while reading Greiner's Quantum Mechanics Symmetries. For the sake of clarity I will omit the hat ($\hat{A}$) symbol on operators.
The quantum mechanical Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector can be defined as
$$ \mathbf{A} = \frac{4\pi\epsilon_0}{\mu Z e^2}\left( \mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{L}-i\hbar\mathbf{p} \right) - \hat{\mathbf{r}}. $$
Together with the angular momentum operator $\mathbf{L}$, we can write down the following commutator relations (for details, see e.g. this, or this question I recently posted):
$$ [L_j, L_k] = i\hbar\varepsilon_{jkl}L_l, $$
$$ [A_j, L_k] = i\hbar\varepsilon_{jkl}A_l, $$
$$ [A_j, A_k] = -i\left(\frac{32\pi^2\epsilon_0^2\hbar}{\mu Z^2 e^4}\right)H\varepsilon_{jkl}L_l, $$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator.
We know that $\{L_1,L_2,L_3\}$ form a closed algebra and are generators of the Lie group $SO(3)$. But if we add in $\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$ they no longer form a closed algebra, although they do come close; the problem is with the operator $H$. Now Greiner says

However, given that $H$ is independent of time and commutes with $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{A}^1$, we can restrict ourselves to a subspace of the Hilbert space that corresponds to a particular eigenvalue $E$ of $H$. Then $H$ in (14.13) can be replaced by its eigenvalue $E$.

After this substitution, we find that the six components above form a closed algebra, and generate the Lie group $SO(4)$. However, I am having a hard time understanding the quoted paragraph.
I would like to ask "why" we can carry on this procedure, namely why time-independence and commutativity allows us to pick the said subspace, and what such a subspace corresponding to some fixed $E$ would look like.$^2$

$^1$ The symbol used in the book is $\mathbf{M}$ instead of $\mathbf{A}$.
$^2$ I believe the the answer in Is this really SO(4) algebra? doesn't explicitly answer this question. Also, I don't know what Poisson brackets have to do with this in the answer, and what "as good as a constant" precisely means.

if you replace $H$ by a constant then your commutator of two $A$’s is now in the algebra as this commutator is an angular momentum.

Note that, strictly speaking, most analyses only show that the Lie algebra involved is $so(4)$.  There are five Lie groups with the algebra, only one of which is $SO(4)$.

Probable duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692328/

This question is similar to: Is this really $SO(4)$ algebra?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ValterMoretti I have edited the question to account for the said duplicity.

Small technical detail, it’s $SO(4)$ for bound states with $E<0$ (particle on a hypersphere) but $SO(3,1)$ for unbound states $E>0$ (particle in Poincaré space)

This is not the math site. Just follow the strategy of wikipedia and, noting that H commutes with L and A, it can be moved out of their commutators just like a constant number. (In its diagonal representation, it may be thought of as a diagonal array of its eigenvalues, positive or negative, discrete or continuous.) So, then, define
$$
D^j\equiv \frac{ A^j}{\sqrt{\frac{32\pi^2\epsilon_0^2H}{\mu Z^2 e^4}}}
$$
to immediately obtain
$$ [L_j, L_k] = i\hbar\varepsilon_{jkl}L_l, \\
  [D_j, L_k] = i\hbar\varepsilon_{jkl}D_l, \\ [D_j, D_k] = -i \hbar
 \varepsilon_{jkl}L_l. $$
This should remind you of the two ideals of the Lorentz group algebra,
$$
{\mathbf S}\equiv { { \mathbf L} +i  { \mathbf D}\over 2\sqrt{\hbar} },\\
{\mathbf R}\equiv { { \mathbf L} -i  { \mathbf D}\over 2\sqrt{\hbar} }, \leadsto \\
[S_j, S_k] = i\varepsilon_{jkl}S_l,\\
 [R_j, R_k] = i\varepsilon_{jkl}R_l,\\
 [S_j, R_k]=0,
$$
the well-known $\mathfrak{su(2)}\oplus \mathfrak {su(2)}$ Lie algebra of  SO(4).
As a consequence, Pauli (1925) explained why the spectrum of Hydrogen has this exceptionally large degeneracy: the generators S and R connect all states within the subspace of such sharing an eigenvalue E.

I would like some clarification on what you meant by $H$ can be moved out of their commutators like a constant number. As far as I understand, we have $[A_j, A_k] = i()\varepsilon_{jkl}HL_l$, where $H$ appears on the right hand side only; so are you saying we need ot calculate some "commutator of commutators", which is why the italicised property is important?

Divide both sides by $H (...)$, and then slip the $1/\sqrt H$ s into each entry in the commutator to obtain the D s...
